# PHP get values from another page

Tags: php, mysql, session, hyperlink, dreamweaver

I have this page admin_inquiry.php(page1) which has a dynamic table that shows rows of records.I want to get the values from 2 columns, ContactNo, and message. The contactno column contains a link, which goes to admin_sms.php(page2) and displays the contact no in a textfield.

page1:

```
<td><a href="admin_sms.php?ContactNo=<?php echo $row_ContactUs['ContactNo']; ?>">Send SMS</a></td>
```

page2:

```
<input name='number' type='text' id="number" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['ContactNo'])){echo $_GET['ContactNo'];}else{echo "";}?>">
```

I also want to get the content of column message from the 1st page and show it in a textarea in page 2. But it should show the message the belongs to particular id or something. I heard of sessions but I don't quite get it yet. Could you show me how?

**UPDATE**
I tried this in the admin_inquiry.php

```
$_SESSION['message'] = $row_ContactUs['message'];
```

admin_sms.php

```
$_SESSION['message'];

<textarea name="frmMsg" id="frmMsg" cols="45" rows="5"><?php echo $_SESSION['message'];?></textarea>
```

The problem is, it's showing the same message. Not the corresponding message that belongs to a certain id or something.Help me please.

Comment: You can create a [Session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) variable and assign a value.  You can use the variable in another page.

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran Updated post. It's not showing the corresponding message. it shows the same thing. T__T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still having problems solving this, in your table include a `html form`

**UPDATE including pagination**

first solution, create a file and call it contact.php

```
<?php  
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=data','root','');
$contacts = $db->query('SELECT * FROM contactdetails');

//creating pagination
$nav_counter = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); //getting name of the current page
$current_page = $nav_counter;
$nav_counter = rtrim($nav_counter, ".php"); //getting the name of the current page and removing the extension

//creating pagination pages
$next_page = $nav_counter + 1;
$prev_page = $nav_counter - 1;

//getting row count, we are going to use it to limit our query and to create pagination
$row_count = $contacts->rowCount();

//number of records to show per page
$num_records = 5;

//getting the last page
$last_page = ($row_count / $num_records) - 1;
    if(!is_int($last_page)){
    $last_page = (int)$last_page + 1;
  }

//displaying records 
$start = 0;
$limit = $num_records; //number of records to show

if ($current_page !== 'admin_inquiry.php'){
    $start = ($limit * $nav_counter);
}

//getting number of rows left in the table
$rows_left = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contactdetails ORDER BY ID limit $start,$limit");
$num_rows = $rows_left->rowCount();

//if records left in the table is less than the number of records to show $num_records
if ($num_rows < $num_records) {
    $limit = $num_rows; //limit is equal to the number of records left in the table
}

//getting number of records from the table
$contacts = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contactdetails ORDER BY ID limit $start,$limit");

//displaying pagination and creating pages if they don't exists
 $pages = array();
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $last_page; $counter++) { 
 $pages[] = $counter;
}
//storing pages in array and creating a page if it doesn't exist
foreach ($pages as $num) {
$page = $num.'.php';
if(file_exists($page)== false && $num <= $last_page){
    copy('admin_inquiry.php', $page);
 }
} 
?>
```

create a pagination.php file

```
<p class="pagenav"><a href="<?php if($current_page == '1.php'){ echo 'admin_inquiry.php';}else{echo $prev_page.'.php';}  ?>" <?php if($current_page == 'admin_inquiry.php'){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>&lt;</a> <a href="<?php echo $next_page.'.php'; ?>" <?php if($next_page > $last_page){echo 'class="hide"';} ?>>&gt;</a></p>
```

create a css file admin.css

```
table {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
table, td, th {
border: 1px solid black;
 }

th {
height: 50px;
}
#div{
width: 40%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.pagenav a{
display: inline;
width: 100px;
padding: 10px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 50px;
font-size: 20px;
color: #fff;
line-height: 50px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #0186ba;
  }
.pagenav a:hover{
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #000;
color: #000;
}
.hide {
display: none !important;
}
p{
text-align: center;
}
```

admin_iquiry.php file

```
 <?php 
  require_once('contact.php');
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="div">
    <table>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Contact No.</th>
         <th>Message</th>
      </tr>
     <?php foreach ($contacts as $value) : ?>
          <tr><td><?php echo $value['ID']; ?></td><td><?php echo $value['ContactNO']; ?></td><td><?php echo $value['Message'] ?></td><td><form action="admin_sms.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="ContactNo" value="<?php echo $value['ContactNO']; ?>"><input type="hidden" name="Message" value="<?php echo $value['Message']; ?>"><input type="Submit" value="Send SMS" name="send_sms" /></form></td></tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <?php require_once('pagination.php'); ?>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

admin_sms.php

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['send_sms'])){
$contactNo = $_POST['ContactNo'];
$message = $_POST['Message'];
}

?>
```

html code

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:50%">
 <p>Message for: <?php echo $contactNo; ?></p>
<textarea><?php echo "$message"; ?></textarea>
```

[image]

Second solution using `$_GET`

```
<?php 
  require_once('contact.php');
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="div">
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Contact No.</th>
    <th>Message</th>
</tr>
foreach ($contacts as $value) : ?>
    <tr><td><?php echo $value['ID']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['ContactNO']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $value['Message'] ?></td>
            //use id of the contact no and in the next page use that id to query data related to that id
            <td><a href="admin_sms.php?id=<?php echo $value['ID']; ?>">Send Sms</a></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </table>
   <?php require_once('pagination.php'); ?>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

admin_sms.php

```
<?php 
 $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=data','root','');
 if(isset($_GET['id'])){
 $id= $_GET['id'];
 $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM contactdetails WHERE ID = $id");
 foreach ($results as  $value) {
       $contactNo = $value['ContactNO'];
      $message = $value['Message'];
     }
   }

 ?>
```

in your html

```
<div style="margin:0 auto; width:50%">
  <p>Message for: <?php echo $contactNo; ?></p>
<textarea><?php echo "$message"; ?></textarea>
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It's now working. Thanks so much for your help. Will definitely learn from this.

Comment: How to show only 5 records at a time?then have prev,next for it.

Comment: I got the limit 5 records right. 'SELECT * FROM inqproduct ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 5'
Just, how to have that prev,next thingy to show the rest of the records?

Comment: Trying the 1st solution. What's that 1.php?

Comment: @MarkTu i think is '.php' where do you see 1.php?

Comment: in pagination.php file. hehe

Comment: got it working now. XD Thanks so much again. you're awesome. I learned new stuff today.

Comment: to check if current page is `1.php` then echo `admin_inquiry.php` in prev page url

Comment: if i click the next button will it always be equal to 1.php? because i have other tables to apply the codes to.

Comment: @MarkTu no it will increment automatically, if you are on page `1.php` the next button will be `2.php` the `$next_page` get the current page and add 1 to make the next page.

Comment: it auto made a 1.php page. I applied the scripts to a new page with a new table and it directs to the same 1.php page of the admin_inquiry, not the supposed next page of the new table in a new page. hmmm

Comment: @MarkTu the script will automatically create pages depending on the number of rows in the table, if there are 16 rows the script will create 3 pages `1.php, 2.php` and `3.php` you don't need to provide script or create pages yourself, php will take care of that.

Comment: is it possible to have more than 1 table in admin_inquiry?or can I apply these scripts to other pages with other tables?

Comment: @MarkTu its possible, you can have as many table as you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1 :**

Use the `POST` method to submit the form. That way, you can query the Message element, pertaining the Contact No., depending on what name or Id you have given to the `<td>` elements. (you have not given any yet).

**Approach 2 :**

Set the href property of the contact No. element dynamically, using, say `jQuery`. Set the action attribute to a URL that includes both the ContactNo and Message as `URL parameters`. That way you can access the message also from the `GET` array just as you are doing with the Contact No. (Note : Not sure if long texts like message can be passed on as URL parameters, depends on the length, and may be security issues).

Comment: Both code lines showing the the SESSION variable neither show that you are putting it or getting it, you just mentioned it. 
While putting it or assigning it :
$_SESSION['message'] = "Some message goes here";
While fetching it in the second page : 
$MyLocalVarInPage2 = $_SESSION['message'];
echo(' For testing : ' . $MyLocalVarInPage2);

Comment: how do you assign $_SESSION['message'] equal to a value in a dynamic table? You see, in admin_inquiry.php a column there shows the messages from a database field like this <td><?php echo $row_ContactUs['message']; ?></td>

Comment: updated to $_SESSION['message'] = $row_ContactUs['message']; and it still shows the same message. not the corresponding one. T_T