# PHP Display uploaded image to a different page

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, dreamweaver

Hi I'm having trouble with this. A user uploads an image in page1.php. It's filename inserts to a database and the image goes to a folder named 'uploads' How do you get those images and show it to page2.php?

page 1

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename'])){
  $errors = array();
  $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
  $file_size =$_FILES['filename']['size'];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
  $file_type=$_FILES['filename']['type'];   
  $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['filename']['name'])));


  $expensions= array("jpeg","jpg","png");         
  if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
    $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a JPEG or PNG file.";
   }
    if($file_size > 2097152){
    $errors[]='File size must be excately 2 MB';
   }          

   //if no error...     
   if (empty($errors)==true) {

    // upload the file...
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = " ";
    $dbname = "admin";

    // create new record in the database
   include ("dbinfo.php");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO payment_form (Tracking, date, ContactNo, totalsent, datesent, filename) VALUES ('$transactionNo', NOW(), '$contactNo', '$totalSent', '$dateSent', '$file_name')") ;

    header('Location: paymentform_success.php');
     }else{
      print_r($errors);
     }
 }
```

page 2 has an update records table. I just want the image to show on a cell there. T__T I haven't researched anything that worked for me.Please help

Comment: Have you tried any query in page 2?

Comment: @AlimonKarim not yet. I'm not sure how.

Comment: @AlimonKarim tried this and not working
$query = "SELECT filename FROM payment_form where Tracking=".$_GET['Tracking']. ";";

Comment: @MarkTu page 2 is `paymentform_success.php`?

Comment: @Jay_P page 1 is admin_payment. page2 is admin_verifypayment and paymentform_success is just to direct the page where the upload file script is located,which is paymentform.php.

Comment: @MarkTu you only want to show the recently uploaded image or all images?

Comment: @Jay_P The image that belongs to a certain id or in my case,the Tracking

Comment: @MarkTu where do get that id? does the user enter it in text box?

Comment: @Jay_P No. In admin_payment I have a table with rows of records.each row has a Verify link. then if i click Verify, it goes to admin_verifypayment.php and the contents of that certain record is shown.I need to show the image that belongs to that record.

Comment: @MarkTu from what i see, you are still learning php, yet you are using mysql_query. whoever is responsible for teaching you php need to start teaching you to use the new mysqli or PDO as they are more secure than what you are using.

Comment: @MarkTu mark the correct answers please!, you ask questions and you don't mark them as answers.

Comment: @LetmeSuckitBaby I was still trying them so I didn't mark it until it really solved my problem. I got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM payment_form";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('SQL error');
}
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Tracking']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['date']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['ContactNo']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['totalsent']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['datesent']}</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='/uploads/{$row['filename']}'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

first you need to run mysql_query with "**SELECT**" query, then run a function like **mysql_fetch_assoc** to get each row and then output the information.

Also, your original code has a SQL injection vulnerability, you have to use **mysql_real_escape_string** for all values submitted by user, e.g.

```
$transactionNo=mysql_real_escape_string($transactionNo);
$contactNo=mysql_real_escape_string($contactNo);
$totalSent=mysql_real_escape_string($totalSent);
$dateSent=mysql_real_escape_string($dateSent);
$file_name=mysql_real_escape_string($file_name);
```

**UPD** To get specific file by tracking id you can use something like this:

```
<?php
$Tracking = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Tracking']);
$query = "SELECT Tracking,filename FROM payment_form WHERE Tracking = '$Tracking'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('SQL error');
}
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['Tracking']}</td>";
    echo "<td><img src='/uploads/{$row['filename']}'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Hi. I already have a table. Can I paste that script to a cell?did it like this and it didn't show the image.can you check?It should show the image that belongs to a certain id number or something.<td><?php
    include ('dbinfo.php');
$query = "SELECT filename FROM payment_form";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('SQL error');
}
echo "<table>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src='/uploads/{$row['filename']}'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?></td>

Comment: Are you sure you have the data in the database?

Comment: yes.how do you show the image that belongs to a certain id in the records?

Comment: Sorry, I've used "filename" rather than  "file_name", probably that's why it wasn't working for you, please use updated code. Also, PLEASE do not use $_GET(and other client-submitted data) straight in the mysql_query, first use mysql_real_escape_string, otherwise your website will be hacked very quickly.

Comment: I tried this, it says SQL Error
$query = "SELECT filename FROM payment_form WHERE Tracking=" .$_GET['Tracking'] . ";";

Comment: It's saying Undefined index for Tracking and file_name for these lines echo "<td>{$row['Tracking']}</td>";
echo "<td><img src='/uploads/{$row['file_name']}'/></td>";
Btw, i pasted the code on page 2 where I want to show the image.Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Could you add var_dump($row); before echo "<tr>";, this way you'll see what data you get from mysql_fetch_assoc function

Comment: aside from the undefined indexes, got this
 array(1) { ["filename"]=> string(6) "g2.jpg" }

Comment: Sorry, I got names(filename vs file_name) wrong again :) please use updated code, namely: you have to fetch Tracking and filename columns from the database to get them displayed on the page, and use $row['filename'] rather than $row['file_name']

Comment: Ok.It's  not giving me errors now. The tracking is fetched and beside it is a "broken image"(?) icon. T__T I'm certain the image filename is in the db and the image itself is in the right folder. We're almost there i think. Please stay with me.

Comment: Open the source of the page and check what URL it generated for img, probably it's just a matter of specifying correct directory, e.g. if this script is  not located at the root of the webserver, then you have to remove first slash: e.g echo "<td><img src='uploads/{$row['filename']}'/></td>";

Comment: It worked! Removing the first slash did the trick. :D Thanks a lot but last question, how do I resize the image to a certain height and width?

Comment: You can check php documentation here(see example #1): http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Answer (score 0):

You do the same thing as i have shown you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259850/php-get-values-from-another-page/28262793#28262793), you can either use `$_GET` or include a form in your table and use `$_POST`. under your verify link you echo the id of each record `<a href="verify.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>">verify link</a>`

on the next page you use `$GET`

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  code here
}
```