# Edit Mysql table with PHP with edit hyperlink

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking the plunge into PHP and Mysql and have run into a wall on how to edit  my database table after displaying my output. I am looking to add a column to my table that will provide a edit hyperlink that will bring me to another page with the record so I can update it.

Below is my code so far.

```
<?php
//Open a new connection to the MySQL server
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname','username','password','database');

//Output any connection error
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//MySqli Select Query
  $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT emp_num, name, supervisor FROM train2015 ORDER BY name desc");

print '<table border="1">';
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
print '<tr>';
print '<td>'.$row->emp_num.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row->name.'</td>';
print '<td>'.$row->supervisor.'</td>';
print '</tr>';
}  

print '</table>';

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

I have added the below to achieve what I was looking for to make the hyperlinks.

```
print '<td>';
print '<a href="edituser.php?=$row[emp_num]"">Edit</a>';
print '</td>';
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What would be the best way to add a column with a edit hyperlink that will bring me to new page to edit the record displayed.

Comment: I've seen this question before. Homework? You need to add another table cell and place a form in that table cell. The form will then call the edit page for the record in that table row.

Comment: Nope. Not homework, trying to learn php and mysql by creating a small database for work that will track our employees attendance to trainings. I've looked around the web for help but couldn't find something that fit my needs. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LanceHietpas are you looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259850/php-get-values-from-another-page/28262793#28262793 ?

Comment: @Jay_P Awesome! Thanks for the link! I'll look it over plug away and see what I can produce.

Comment: I've made some progress which I will add to the main question.